# Creation date of the initial post

Tags: support, edits

In some posts I've read, which have been edited repeatedly, it's not actually clear, without a bit of searching through the edits, when a post was first created. As an example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage) has been edited numerous times, and the post footer...

[image]

...does not display the initial creation date, simply the last edited date. Is there any reason why both dates aren't displayed?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with [community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the right of the screen there is an area that displays when it was asked. If you hover your mouse over the label it will display an exact date/time which is what the site does for all fields that show a date/time when something happened.

[image]

For non community wiki answers (or questions) the time of the original  post will be visible as well as the last edit. However for a community wiki answer the only way to get the original post would be to look at the edit history

[image]

Comment: Damn!  You're absolutely right! *<slaps forehead>*  You do realise that my date maths are terrible, though!

Comment: @Paul Hover your pointer over that label and have the math done for you.

Comment: @yivi - That does it - I'm going back to bed!  I should never have got up this morning!

Comment: @Paul, reason to vote to close your day: unclear why you woke up

Comment: But what about **answers**? How do you see the creation date of *those*?

Comment: @EthanK888 For answers you can always use the edit history and look at the initial revision

Comment: @JoeW Is there **no** better way? SO should really change that.

Comment: @EthanK888 Not for a community wiki answer.

Comment: @JoeW `:(` That should *really* be fixed.